# Can a default service/module in a Google App Engine app be a sibling of a non-default one in terms of folder structure?

Tags: google-app-engine, module

Update: `modules` are called `services` these days.

I would like to organize my project's modules into various subfolders, where each subfolder contains code pertaining to each module. In particular, I would like the folder containing the default module to be on the same level as other modules (i.e. they are all siblings). I am following the diagram shown in the [Modules documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/an-overview-of-app-engine):

[image: diagram]
<sub>(source: [google.com](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/images/modules_yaml_files2.png))</sub>

However, what confuses me is the statement "[Important: The app.yaml file must be located in your application's root directory](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref?hl=en)". Does this imply that the default module (and its app.yaml) must be in the project root directory, and therefore, be the parent of non-default modules?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The modules can all be side by side. The `<module>.yaml` for each one can be inside the module dir.

The note about `app.yaml` file is misleading, it really applies just to single-module apps (many pieces of the documentation weren't updated for multi-module apps).

The `default` module's config file doesn't even have to be called `app.yaml` (or its dir called `default`). I'd keep the app-level config files (`cron.yaml`, `dispatch.yaml`, `queue.yaml` and `index.yaml`) at the top level, eventually symlinking them into the default (or other) module(s) as needed (some tools may complain otherwise).

Here's, for example, the structure I got to for one of my apps (the `main` dir contains the `default` module):

```
cron.yaml
dispatch.yaml
queue.yaml
index.yaml
main/cron.yaml -> ../cron.yaml
main/index.yaml -> ../index.yaml
main/main.yaml
main/queue.yaml -> ../queue.yaml
buildin/buildin.yaml
buildin/index.yaml -> ../index.yaml
buildin/queue.yaml-> ../queue.yaml
```

You just need to pay attention when invoking the related tools. This is my cheat-sheet for that app, executed from the app's dir, some of it is also reflected in the pycharm project config (I'm running the development server inside pycharm):

```
appcfg.py update main/main.yaml buildin/buildin.yaml
appcfg.py update_dispatch .
appcfg.py update_indexes -A <app-name> main
appcfg.py update_cron -A <app-name> .
appcfg.py update_queues -A <app-name> .
```

To run the devserver:

```
dev_appserver.py --host 0.0.0.0 --log_level=debug dispatch.yaml main/main.yaml buildin/buildin.yaml
```

**Update:** added some of my config files, as requested.

The `dispatch.yaml` file, taking care of the `buildin` module routing on both the appspot domain and my custom domain (everything else is automatically routed to the default module):

```
application: <my_app>
dispatch:
  - url: "buildin.my_domain.com/*"
    module: buildin
  - url: "buildin-dot-my_app.appspot.com/*"
    module: buildin
  - url: "*/buildin/*"
    module: buildin
```

The `main.yaml` file:

```
application: my_app
module: default
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /(.*\.min\.css)$
  static_files: stylesheets/\1
  upload: stylesheets/.*\.min\.css$
  secure: always

- url: /(.*\.(ico|gif|png|jpg|svg))$
  static_files: images/\1
  upload: images/.*\.(ico|gif|png|jpg|svg)$
  secure: always

- url: .*
  script: main.app
  secure: always

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"
```

The `buildin.yaml` file:

```
application: my_app
module: buildin
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
instance_class: B2

handlers:

- url: /(.*\.min\.js)$
  static_files: scripts/\1
  upload: scripts/.*\.min\.js$
  secure: always

- url: /(.*\.min\.css)$
  static_files: stylesheets/\1
  upload: stylesheets/.*\.min\.css$
  secure: always

- url: /(.*\.(ico|gif|png|jpg|svg))$
  static_files: images/\1
  upload: images/.*\.(ico|gif|png|jpg|svg)$
  secure: always

- url: /buildin/cron*
  script: buildin.app
  login: admin

- url: .*
  script: buildin.app
  secure: always

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and for providing the example along with the cheat sheet. It is very useful.

Comment: @dan , can you paste in your dispatch.yaml + main/main.yaml + buildin/buildin.yaml code ?

Comment: @Kevin Lee, I'm still not able to figure it out getting this error. google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: Unexpected attribute 'dispatch' for object of type AppInfoExternal.
  in "./app.yaml", line 3, column 3

Please give me a working code, if possible. sirimala.sreenath@gmail.com

Comment: @sreenathsirimala: Ask it as a separate question. Include the entire trace and the content of your yaml file.