# Cannot upload project - appcfg.py permission denied

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to upload my newly created project to app engine but receiving "permission denied" when running `appcfg.py update .` in my project directory.

Things I have tried:

- Tried specifying the full path to project `appcfg.py update **path**`
- Tried checking permissions on appcfg.py and appcfg.pyc are read & write
- Tried following all answers found on the only relevant post I can find: [google app engine - permission denied error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683112/google-app-engine-permission-denied-error)
- Ran `gcloud auth login` and logged into google via Chrome.

No idea what else I can do, I'm new to this and this problem is just confusing me further.

Answer (score 1):

I used `gcloud app deploy` instead and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I usually receive this error when not specifying python before appcfg.py.
For example:

```
python appcfg.py update ~/mycodeproject/app.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to change access permission of the `appcfg.py` file.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod read more about `chmod` here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 # python2.7 /usr/local/bin/appcfg.py update app.yaml
```

This is the call I do having both python2.7 and python3.x on my mac.