# How do I access a vendored library from a module in Python Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am getting an ImportError when I try to access a library inside the lib directory in my application root.

I did the necessary steps in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring) and it worked with only one module but once I moved to this directory structure with multiple modules it no longer works:

```
<app root>
  |
  +-- appengine_config.py
  |
  +-- lib
  |
  +-- modules     
      +-- module1
      |
      +-- module2
```

In my appengine_config.py I add the line: `vendor.add(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib'))`

Any thoughts on what might be going on here?

Edit:
This directory structure that seemed to work for me:

```
<app root>
  |
  +-- lib
  |     
  +-- module1
  |     +-- appengine_config.py
  |     |
  |     +-- app.yaml
  |     |
  |     +-- lib <symlink to app root lib>
  +-- module2 (same as module 1)
```

I thought that appengine_config.py was something to be defined at the main application level and not the module level. Is it correct to duplicate the same exact file and sym linking in each module.

Comment: Where are your modules' `.yaml` files located? I mean did you follow the 1st or the 2nd app structure suggestion in the doc: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Configuration

Comment: The top level yaml files like `queue.yaml`, `cron.yaml`, etc are in the app root directory while the `app.yaml` files are in `modules/module1`, `modules/module2`  directories. I followed mostly the first app structure but nested all my modules inside the module directory. Sorry for the naming confusion as it may get mixed up with your standard Python modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each module directory is uploaded as a standalone application and it needs all its files inside that module directory (i.e. nothing from the module's **parent** directory is uploaded/visible in the module). The module directory is the one containing the module's `.yaml` file, so in your case they'll be the `modules/module1` and `modules/module2` dirs.

So symlink the `lib` dir and the `appengine_config.py` from the app's dir  into the modules' dirs. In addition, for my app, as Tim mentions, the vendoring line that works is indeed just `vendor.add('lib')`. Copying them works just as well, but symlinking is better as you only need to maintain one copy in your version control system, in the DRY spirit. The `appcfg.py` script knows to follow the symlinks and upload the actuall files the symlinks point to.

If you don't need *all* but only *some* of the libs in a module you can create a `lib` dir in that module dir and only symlink the necessary subdirs of the app's `lib` dir into the respective module's `lib` dir (to not upload unnecessary files).

You *might* need to also symlink into some of the module dirs other app-level config files to keep some of the supporting scripts happy on the development server, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34111170/4495081. Note that updating the app-level configs may not happen simply by uploading the modules' code as mentioned in the single-module app tutorials, they'll need to be requested explicitly with the corresponding arguments of `appcfg.py`, as mentioned in the cheat sheet in that answer.

Comment: Thank you all so much.  Great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you including os.path.dirname(**file**) in vendor.add ?

Look at the docs.  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27?hl=en#vendoring

`vendor.add('lib')` or at worst
`vendor.add('lib/modules')` is all you need.

Is `modules` really a module/package ?

Comment: I had `vendor.add('lib')` originally but it didn't work either so I just tried the tip mentioned in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27?hl=en#vendoring).

`modules` is the directory where I kept all my modules. Wanted to organize all my different modules in one place.

Comment: I've also just tried moving all my app engine modules down a level from inside the modules directory to just inside the app root. I am testing with `dev_appserver.py` btw.

Comment: It actually seems like `appengine_config.py` isn't being run at all when it's in the app root. When I move it to inside module1 and create a symlink in module1 to point to the main lib directory it seems to actually run the file.

Edited my original question for something that seems to help.