# Google App Engine - Multiple yaml files in one project share a lib

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I want to create a multi-serivce app engine app, using the first diagram shown on this page. 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/configuration-files#an_example

I want to use third party libraries so I used have a lib folder under the root directory, one yaml under the root directory. 
Then I want one microservice called predict. So I created a folder called predict under the root directory as well, then under this folder, I want to write py files using the packages in the lib as well.

What I'm doing is like this:

```
import os,sys,inspect
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
vendor.add(os.path.join(parentdir, 'lib'))
```

Which didn't work for me as the error says:

```
ValueError: virtualenv: cannot access /base/data/home/apps/f~project-name/lib: No such virtualenv or site directory
```

Obviously it didn't work for me, what's the right way to do this?

**Update**: Dan's solution worked for me! So when I'm deploying my microservice predict, I need to go inside predict directory and deploy it. I think that's why it can't find lib. By symlink the lib library using bash.

```
ln -s ../lib/ ./lib
```

I solved this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that each service can only access files in its own service directory, which is the directory where its `app.yaml` file is located, they can't access the app's root directory.

My approach (all my services use standard environment):

- created a `lib` dir in the top app dir and installed in it each package that I want shared across multiple services
- each service has its own subdir in the app's dir and a `lib` directory in it where:

  - I installed libraries needed only by that service (if any)
  - I symlinked the needed shared libraries from the top `lib` dir

This is my app dir structure:

```
app_dir/
app_dir/dispatch.yaml
app_dir/cron.yaml
app_dir/index.yaml
app_dir/queue.yaml
app_dir/lib/
app_dir/lib/shared_lib_1/
app_dir/lib/shared_lib_2/
app_dir/lib/shared_lib_3/
app_dir/service1/
app_dir/service1/app.yaml
app_dir/service1/lib/shared_lib_1 -> ../../lib/shared_lib_1
app_dir/service1/lib/shared_lib_2 -> ../../lib/shared_lib_2
app_dir/service1/lib/service1_lib_1
app_dir/service2/
app_dir/service2/app.yaml
app_dir/service2/lib/shared_lib_2 -> ../../lib/shared_lib_2
app_dir/service2/lib/shared_lib_3 -> ../../lib/shared_lib_3
app_dir/service2/lib/service2_lib_1
```

No fumbling with the lib path is required, all I have in each service is

```
vendor.add('lib')
```

See related:

- [How do I access a vendored library from a module in Python Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973058/how-do-i-access-a-vendored-library-from-a-module-in-python-google-app-engine/34985211#34985211)
- [Can a default service/module in a Google App Engine app be a sibling of a non-default one in terms of folder structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110178/can-a-default-service-module-in-a-google-app-engine-app-be-a-sibling-of-a-non-de?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Could you just symlink the whole lib dir?  Not sure if that would make much of a difference in resource usage.

Comment: Symlinking the entire `lib` dir is possible (I actually started that way) but only if  if all services have the same needs. It does matter in the app file quota - at deployment time the symlinks are replaced by their content, so the number of files in a symlinked shared lib will be multiplied by the number of services sharing it. If pulling heavy libs the impact could be significant.

Answer (score 0):

Check all the directories in the path and the final file to make sure they all exist first before code runs. If they don't, prepend the code you showed here with code to create them...