# Base Directory for a module in App Engine yaml file

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-module

I started working with App Engine today and I am trying to find a way to set a root folder for each of my modules/services. Example:

**Folder Structure**

- /mod1/*
- /mod2/*
- dispatch.yaml
- app.yaml
- mod1.yaml
- mod2.yaml

Is it possible to set the base directory for a module in App Engine yaml file?

Something similar to `RewriteBase /` in apache. This way in my **mod1.yaml** I dont have to specify the **mod1** directory 30 time for each endpoints.

Maybe a commend in the dispactch.yaml

```
  - url: "api-dot-lyreka-com.appspot.com/"
    module: api
    path: /mod1 -- Just for example. Something like that
```

I have been looking for a couple hours now.

Comment: I tried `document_root: api` but that does not work. I guess it's more for the PHP side

Answer (score 1):

Just move the module `.yaml` files inside the respective module dir which makes that module dir become the "root" of the module, so you don't need to specify it anymore. More details here:

- [Run Google App Engine application with microservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125926/run-google-app-engine-application-with-microservice?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [New project structure for Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608403/new-project-structure-for-google-app-engine/35615388#35615388)

**Note:** each module only sees what's inside its "root" dir, nothing *above* it is deployed when the module is deployed. But you can symlink stuff in each of the module dir to share it across modules: [Sharing entities between App Engine modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291075/sharing-entities-between-app-engine-modules/34291789#34291789)