# How to deploy one app engine app to multiple projects

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My problem is that I want to create `dev`, `stage`, `prod` environments by using different GCP projects.

Basically they are running the same code, just running them in different isolated environments.

I'm using `gcloud app deploy` in command line to deploy app right now.

How can I efficiently deploy an app to different project?
Do I have to do `gcloud init` to change my configuration of default project every time?
There must be some better practices.

Or, is there a better way for me to set up `dev`... environments in the context of app engine?

Thanks.

Comment: create a deployment script that utilize multi processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python applications, you can set application in the app.yaml file.  This allows you to use different data for each project.  This is when you deploy using the appcfg.py command.

```
application: myproject
version: alpha-001
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  script: home.app
```

If you don't want to change the application value in this file for each project, you can run the following:

```
appcfg.py -A <YOUR_PROJECT_ID> -V v1 update myapp/
```

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref

> If you do not specify the application in the file, use the --application option in the appcfg command when you deploy. This element is ignored when you deploy using the gcloud app deploy command.

Comment: thank you Jeff! This is very handy. But I'm using flexible app engine right now. Didn't see this `application` field in the `app.yaml` documentation. Might as well just try it, see if works like standard app engine.

Comment: It turns out I could use `gcloud beta app deploy --project project-name` to deploy the same code to different isolated project.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `gcloud init` to change your configuration each time, use this code to deploy to multiple projects faster:

```
gcloud app deploy -q --project [YOUR_PROJECT_ID]
```

If your projects have similar IDs, let's say: `test1`, `test2`, `test3`, `test4`, You can deploy to the four projects with one command. Use this code:

```
for i in {1..4}; do gcloud app deploy -q --project test${i}; done
```

Answer (score 2):

The "standard" approach is to use versions, e.g.

```
qa.myApp.appspot.com
```

Once a version is ready for next step, you deploy it with a different version id.

One problem with using multiple projects is that you have to maintain a different data set for each project.

Comment: I do understand version could do the job. But by doing so, all underlying data store are all mixed up, ex: datastore NoSQL. Wouldn't this defy the purpose of isolated environment?

Comment: You can isolate data in the Datastore by using namespaces, if necessary. It all depends on how your data is organized. In some projects I have a test user account, which has data that is only used for testing and is not mingled with "live" users. In one project I had a test "organization", which was just like any other organization since each organization could access only its own data and did not see other organizations.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I personally want to create more isolated env so I decide to make it to different projects for finer grained control.

Answer (score 2):

My preference is to have the different environments managed via the same version control as the code - one branch for each environment, keeping the deployments perfectly aligned with the natural flow of code changes, promoted via branch merges: `dev` -> `stage` -> `production`.

To minimize the risk of human error I try as much as possible to keep the deployment configs in the code itself (i.e. - have the app IDs, versions, etc. picked up from the `.yaml` files, not passed to the deploy cmd as args). The deployment cmds themselves are kept in a cheat-sheet file (too simple to warrant a full-blown script at this time), also git-controlled. Illustrated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34111170/4495081

Deployments are done from separate, dedicated workspaces - one for each environment, based on the corresponding git branch (I never switch the branches in these workspaces). I just update the workspace corresponding to the desired environment to the version needed and copy-paste the deployment cmd from the workspace's cheat-sheet.

This model is IMHO CI/CD-ready and can easily be entirely automated.