# How to deploy multiple app-engine instances with maven?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have 2 java springboot services to be deployed to google app-engine (standard env). They both work fine and I was able to deploy them both  with `mvn appengine:deploy`.

However the standard environment automatically assigns a name and version to each service and causes them to overwrite one another.

I have already looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395271/how-to-deploy-one-app-engine-app-to-multiple-projects) answer which didn't work in the standard environment.

How do I deploy multiple services with different names so they don't overwrite one another?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the name of the service in the [appengine-web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref) of each application by adding the **<service>** element:

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <runtime>java8</runtime>

  <service>your-service-name</service>

  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```