# AppEngine docs recommend command-line flags instead of app.yaml file elements

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app.yaml

In the [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref) documentation, Google makes the following recommendation of number of times:

> "The recommended approach is to remove the **ELEMENT NAME** [e.g. `application`] from your app.yaml file and instead, use a command-line flag to specify your **ELEMENT NAME** [e.g. `application ID`]"

Unfortunately, Google doesn't explain why they recommend this.

In my opinion, an informative app.yaml file is much more helpful than deploying an app with command-line flags. Can anyone explain why Google makes this recommendation?

Comment: it *might* be from the pre-service/modules days, like the `Important: The app.yaml file must be located in your application's root directory.` note. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34111170/4495081

Answer (score 2):

I think mainly because they are slowly moving away from the `appcfg.py`, to start using the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) instead, where `application` is not supported. You can set your default application so you won't need to use command line all the time.

Comment: Yep, for the application name it seems as a reasonable thing to do, but as for the version name I don't think so, I tried recently to use the cloud sdk for version deployment and it prevented me to write the version name on the app yaml file. Up until now the app yaml file helped me a lot to control the version numeration and management, I guess I'll have to stick with the appcfg.py, thanks mate

Comment: every time you deploy now it deploys to a new version as timestamp.. and it's up to you use the `--no-promote` if you don't want to promote it by default.. or just use the `--version` as usual if you want to have a named version.