# Cron per Service/Module (AppEngine)

Tags: google-app-engine

I have two modules/services and each one has a cron.xml.  Only one of these ever seems to run (the most recently deployed in my experience), and the other doesn't fail, but the endpoint is never triggered (never shows up in the logs).

Is there a 1-cron per project limit?  What is the best way to manage crons so that modules aren't cross-dependant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cron.yaml` is an app-level config file, not a service/module one. Meaning when you deploy the one you have in one module it'll overwrite the cron config from the other one.

So you have to create a **single** `cron.yaml` file containing job configs for **all** services/modules. As @GAEfan mentioned you'll also need add `target` configs for each job. You *might* also need to add a `dispatch.yaml` file and maybe re-visit/adjust the request paths so that the cron job-issued requests make it to the right service/module.

Deploying the app-level `cron.yaml` *might* not be happening implicitly when deploying the service(s), you may need to deploy it explicitly. From 
[Uploading cron jobs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#upload-cron):

> Option 2: Upload only your cron updates
>
> To update just the cron configuration without uploading the rest of
>   the application, run the following command:
>
> ```
> appcfg.py update_cron <app-directory>
> ```

Some more or less related Q&As:

- [Deploying different languages services to the same Application [Google App Engine]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41681288/deploying-different-languages-services-to-the-same-application-google-app-engin)
- [Can a default service/module in a Google App Engine app be a sibling of a non-default one in terms of folder structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110178/can-a-default-module-in-a-google-app-engine-app-be-a-sibling-of-a-non-default-mo?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `target: backend-module-name` parameter inside a cron job you want to send to a module other than default.  Only one `cron.yaml` needed.

Make sure you update: `appcfg.py update app.yaml backend_module.yaml cron.yaml`