# Avoid overwriting cron jobs on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I am using google app engine and have 2 applications that use cron jobs to schedule events. I am able to deploy both applications by using `gcloud app deploy app.yaml cron.yaml`. Even though both apps are deployed and working, only one of the cron jobs actually runs. This is what the files look like.

First cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: "GET first group"
  url: /
  schedule: every 5 minutes
  target: pubsubone
```

Second cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: "GET second group"
  url: /
  schedule: every 5 minutes
  target: pubsubtwo
```

These files are in different folders and associated with different applications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cron per Service/Module (AppEngine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744890/cron-per-service-module-appengine)

Comment: Note that you don't have 2 different applications, but 2 different services/modules inside the same GAE application (project) and that the cron config is an app-level config shared by all services in the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you deploy the second service with a new `cron.yaml` file, the first cron job gets overwritten since only one `cron.yaml` is expected for deployments. To deploy both cron jobs contemporarily join them in a single file, as shown in the example [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref) and then deploy the resulting `cron.yaml` file as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron#upload-cron). The `cron.yaml` should look like this:

```
cron: 
- description: "GET first group" 
url: / 
schedule: every 5 minutes 
target: pubsubone 
- description: "GET second group" 
url: / 
schedule: every 5 minutes 
target: pubsubtwo
```

And the command line to deploy it is this one:

```
$ gcloud app deploy cron.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons this can be failing for you, and sorting out which will be easier if you use something other than `/` as the url. `/cron`, perhaps. That'll make it a lot easier to determine, when looking at the logs, that the url is being called as intended.

Next, there the `target`. If there aren't versions of your app active that have the specified value as their version (or service, though I don't have experience with that), AFAIK, the request generated by `cron` will get dropped on the floor.