# Google App Engine - Could not find dispatch configuration

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I want to create very standard setup for GAE (php runtime): 2 modules with specific URLs (routings):

- module-api for REST API
- module-app for web base application

I've created 4 .yaml config files:
**app.yaml**

```
application: ABC
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

automatic_scaling:
  max_idle_instances: 20

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: api/web/index.php
```

**dispatch.yaml**

```
application: ABC

dispatch:
- url: "*/app/*"
  module: web-based

- url: "*/*"
  module: default
```

**web_based.yaml**

```
application: ABC
module: web-based
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 2
  max_pending_latency: 1s

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|otf))
  static_files: /\1
  upload: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|js|css|otf))
```

api.yaml

```
application: ABC
module: default
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|otf))
  static_files: web/\1
  upload: web/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|js|css|otf))

- url: /assets/(.+)
  static_files: web/assets/\1
  upload: web/assets/(.+)

- url: /.*
  script: web/index.php
```

**Directory structure:**

```
- api/api.yaml
- app/web_base.yaml
- app.yaml
- dispatch
```

When I try update_dispatch, I get dispatch configuration file is not found. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In a multi-module app there is no app-level `app.yaml` anymore, there is only one `.yaml` file for each module and that's it.

So get rid of the top-level `app.yaml` (if needed merge its relevant content into the `api.yaml` file, which is the one for your `default` module). The 2 files collide and can confuse the update_dispatch operation. Then deploy the default module - often it needs to be deployed before app-level configs (like the `dispatch.yaml` file) and the other modules can be deployed.

Maybe peek at [Can a default service/module in a Google App Engine app be a sibling of a non-default one in terms of folder structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110178/can-a-default-module-in-a-google-app-engine-app-be-a-sibling-of-a-non-default-mo), it's for a python app but many things in there like app dir structure, app-level configs (dispatching for example) and deployment are applicable to php as well.

Side notes:

- you're also missing a dynamic handler inside `web_based.yaml`.
- you don't *need* a dispatch rule for the `default` module - that's where the requests with no routes are dispatched to anyways
- personally I'd make the web app the default module and the REST one a non-default one - I wouldn't like all garbage coming in hitting the REST module by default...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have removed app.yaml from root folder and updated both modules. Still getting that error. Any ideas?

Comment: Which is the exact cmd you use and in which dir?

Comment: BTW, your file is actually called `dispatch.yaml`, not `dispatch` as you mention in the directory structure, right?

Comment: Yes, it is dispatch.yaml. I used **appcfg.py update api/api.yaml app/web_base.yaml**. Then trying to run **appcfg.py -A project_name update_dispatch api**.

Comment: Never mind. It seems I entered wrong directory while dispatch command. It worked.