# Map Datastore Admin to a different URL?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

**EDIT:** Upon further inspection, I found that the URL of the Datastore Admin is already `https://ah-builtin-python-bundle-dot-[project-id].appspot.com/_ah/datastore_admin?app_id=[project-id]`. It was probably enabled before the "default" tag was put implemented, so it was catching all traffic into the sub-domain. **So, no need to re-map the URL.**

There is this existing project which I have been added to work on, and it has the [project-id].appspot.com already occupied by a stock Datastore Admin page.

I needed to host a few more appspot URLs, some of which to act as PubSub endpoints, so I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302717/is-there-possibility-to-host-multiple-applications-with-google-app-engine) explaining that all I need to do is add a  service tag in the app.yaml.

However, on deploying, I get this error

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The first service
>   (module) you upload to a new application must be the 'default' service
>   (module). Please upload a version of the 'default' service (module)
>   before uploading a version for the 'upload-watcher' service (module).
>   See the documentation for more information. Python:
>   (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Uploading%%20modules)
>   Java:
>   (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Uploading%%20modules)

with 'upload-watcher' being the service name I assigned to this app engine app.

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507335/map-datastore-admin-to-appengine-service) faced a similar issue, but he sought a different workaround and the answer was merely conceptual.

Mechanically, is this the right code to add into the chosen app.yaml? :

```
service: default
```

Further, it appears to me that the Datastore Admin should NOT be made the default service, and should be kept more or less obscured from public view. Hence, ideally, I would like to remap the datastore admin to a secondary service URL, like

```
datastore-admin-dot-[project-id].appspot.com
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution discussed in the first thread you mention means a separate `.yaml` config file for the new service, not just `a service tag into the app.yaml file` (the existing one).

Personally I recommend keeping the services in separate side-by-side subdirectories inside the GAE app's dir, see an actual example in [Can a default service/module in a Google App Engine app be a sibling of a non-default one in terms of folder structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110178/can-a-default-service-module-in-a-google-app-engine-app-be-a-sibling-of-a-non-de/34111170#34111170)

The error you encounter is similar with the second thread you mentioned: you don't have an already a deployed `default` service when you're trying to deploy the `upload-watcher` service.

Don't over-think the datastore admin "mapping" part too much - you may be misled by the second thread - the datastore admin is not a GAE service/module, it's an app-level facility covering all of the app's services which share the app's datastore. Get your services running first and, if you see problems in this direction ask a separate question, right now it's just adding confusion.

**Update:**

Yes, the `service: default` is correct for the default service. Alternatively you can just have no `service` config in it at all - same effect.

Depending the deployment command used (more specifically the [`--version`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#--version) optional argument) a new service version would be created or an existing version would be overwritten. See also [Continuous integration/deployment/delivery on Google App Engine, too risky?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192557/continuous-integration-deployment-delivery-on-google-app-engine-too-risky/40193364#40193364)

But, as you observed, serving the datastore admin facility is done by default, not specifically enabled via configs, so it'll work regardless or overwriting the existing version or not.

Comment: I understood that the `default` service tag had to go into a different .yaml, for the service that I wish to set as `default`, but is that line of code the right usage?  


Also, I'm worried that if I were to deploy my new service as default, it'll take over the main appspot URL `[project-id].appspot.com`, and the team and users will lose access to the datastore admin? Or will that not be the case?