# How to set the service name of an GCP App Engine service

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I upload my endpoints app to GCP AppEngine and it work nice. 
But in the dashboard, the service name be assigned to 'default'.

How do I set the service name?
Thanks for your support.
[image]

Comment: Note that you can only change the name for the *additional* services, the `default` service is mandatory, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44193480/4495081

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several ways to set a service's name in App Engine. If you use Java with Maven for example, you can:

- set `<module>service_name</module>` in the [appengine-web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref) file

If you use Python, you can:

- set `service: service_name` in the app.yaml file

Comment: `-v` set the version of the service you are deploying. not the service name.

Answer (score 6):

Use `service: service_name` in your `app.yaml` file.

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#general)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I develop with Eclipse and Java. After check the document https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/configuration-files, I cannot find the doc about app.yaml for java, is there have any other way to configure it?

Comment: Also valid for other languages. Example: PHP7, look for element "service" in documentation (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref). Also, note that this may *create* new services. Spot the phrase "Required if creating a service."

Answer (score 0):

Agreed on below answers. I did the same thing in **app.yaml** file in spring-boot appengine and it's working...

```
runtime: java11
instance_class: F4
service: appengine-spring-boot
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: this field is required, but ignored
```