# Using Firestore without enabling App Engine

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I recently disabled App Engine in my project as I don't need it anymore. However, I am now greeted by the following when accessing Firestore in the Firebase console:
[image: Firebase Console]

The problem is that App Engine is pretty costly (min $50/month)

I'd like to know if there is a way to use Firestore without paying this much.

Thanks

**Update:**

You can have app engine enabled for free, but I couldn't get it done for the following reason:

I had in my config (app.yaml) `min_num_instances: 1`. I haven't realised this and whenever I wanted to delete an instance I never could (with no error message: it just did not delete it without displaying anything)

Comment: `App Engine is pretty costly (min $50/month)` - not true. Can you explain how you reached this conclusion?

Comment: Hey Dan, I'll explain. I had in my app.yaml the following:  - min_num_instances: 1, which I overlooked. With this config whenever I wanted to delete the running instances I never could (without any error message btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to use Firestore without having App Engine enabled.

I use Firestore in many of my apps however without ever paying for App Engine. Since App Engine is pay-as-you-use, there is no payment required until you use it.

Comment: Ok great! The problem is that I haven't figured out how to get rid of the default instance without disabling app engine

Comment: @Stormsyders: you can't get rid of the `default` service, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/44178971/4495081. But it can run for free.

Comment: Oh yes, what I meant was to delete all running instances of the default instance. It never worked for me due to bad config (min_num_instances: 1) but it's all good now thanks

Comment: To add to this, if your default service runs in the Standard environment, you can [set a spending limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/#setting_a_spending_limit), by going to the [App Engine settings](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings) within your project. If you set the daily spending limit 0, you will only use the free quota, and won't be billed for the App Engine usage.

Comment: @Stormsyders just deleting the instances may not be enough - they could be restarted, you need to have the config from the version receiving all traffic setup to prevent launching  new instances (or ensuring those launched don't exceed your free quota).

Comment: Why is App Engine required for Firestore?

Comment: It has to do with how Firestore came to be. I recently described it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63404100/app-engine-needs-to-be-enabled-to-use-cloud-firestore/63404405#63404405