# It seems that Firestore is restraining me from create an App Engine application, how can still create one?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to create an App Engine application:

```
Already exists (HTTP 409): Cannot create Firestore database resource projects/xxxxxxxx-xxxxx/databases/(default) since it is already exists at location eur3.
```

As the error states, I already have a Firestore database.

When I run `gcloud app create` I get this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.create) The project [xxxxxxxxx-xxxx] already contains an App Engine application. You can deploy your application using `gcloud app deploy`.
```

And when I run `gcloud app deploy` it forces me into creating a new project (above error).

As I said, I tried to create the app in different ways: using the CLI and through the console. Both don't work, but they both give me a different error message. Other than that I didn't do anything, because I'm quite a beginner with Google Cloud and I don't want to break anything.

Edit:
I've done some more testing by creating new projects. You can reproduce the issue by doing the following:

1. Create GCP / Firebase project using [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).
2. Enable Firestore (using location eur3).
3. Go to [App Engine](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/) and click on Create Application. ([App Engine Create Application Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QMtI.jpg))
4. Use any region (my preferred region is europe-west-3) and click next.
5. It displays an error: [Error image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUqiD.jpg), [Error image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6nBJ.jpg).
6. Go to [activity](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity) and it should display the [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAawa.jpg).

*If I create an App Engine app before setting up firestore, it works but I don't want to create a new project.*

Comment: I should mention this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75646711/unable-to-create-an-appengine-app-in-google-cloud-platform) of 2 months ago. Same issue but not a real solution.

Comment: Since it says the project already contains an App Engine application, why not just try deploying an application to the project e.g. code up a simple hello world app and execute ```gcloud app deploy --project=<project_id>```? That will confirm for you if a GAE application actually exists or not

Comment: @NoCommandLine I already tried that! That command doesn't do anything but forcing me to create a project using the CLI and that doesn't work.

`ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) The project [xxxxx-xxxxx] already contains an App Engine application. You can deploy your application using "gcloud app deploy`

Comment: @Matt please elaborate what does "forcing me to create a project" mean. Where and how is it forcing you?