# Copy specific project files to Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gcloud

I have a Python project running on Google App Engine. My APNS certs are expiring and I would just like to replace those specific cert files. I am struggling to find a way to do that with gcloud. Is it possible to deploy just these two files to my project rather than all project files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, or at least not guaranteed.

Neither `gcloud` nor the GAE-SDK's `appcfg.py` support specifying a subset of the app service's files (besides [a few app-level config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360790/why-do-i-need-to-deploy-a-default-app-before-i-can-deploy-multiple-services-in/42361987#42361987) shared by all of the app's services which can be deployed individually/independently). The smallest deployable unit you can only specify is an app's service and the deployment utility will attempt to bring all the services' file up to date.

But the files you're interested in *might* be the only files being actually uploaded if they are the only files changed since the last deployment of the service. But that is not guaranteed.

Comment: But might I ask why exactly would you mind if other files are also updated?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's an old but still in use project. I was concerned that the files I had might not match the files on the server. To get around this I used appcfg.py to download the files from GAE. I then updated the certs and pushed them all up again. Still it's good to know that there isn't a way to update individual files.