# Microservice on GAE+ Mix of Standard and Flexible GAE Services

Tags: google-app-engine, microservices

We have two separate projects as follows

1. GAE Standard on JAVA runtime, let us say- APP1
2. GAE Flexible on Python runtime, let us say- APP2

We want to move both the projects in one micro-services application project with two services, say APP1service (default), and APP2service.

Wanted to check if it is possible to host standard and flexible GAE services sharing one application identity in microservices setup?

Quick answer is highly appreciated.

ps.

> Google documentation does not answer this question directly and hints
>   that it is unlikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have any mix of environments and languages as separate services inside of the same GAE application. While not explicitly mentioned, it is implied by the code isolation of services. From [App Engine Services as microservices](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine#app_engine_services_as_microservices):

> Code can be deployed to services independently, and different services can be written in different languages, such as Python, Java, Go, and PHP.

You just need to take care of:

- deploying the default service first, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42361987/4495081
- deploying the app-level configurations shared by all services: dispatch, cron, queue, etc.

Comment: Yes, Initial deployment of some services did work. What make me doubting is the **COST ACCOUNTING** in Multi-service pattern as stated:  "Costs for instance-hours (the CPU and memory for running your code) are not separated for services; all the instance-hours for an entire project are lumped together."  As far as I know, flexible and standard instance hours not billed on same pattern, in fact flexible environment would need at least one dedicated instance up all the time to service the requests as opposed to standard instances that can scale automatically?

Comment: flex env services are not billed on instance-hours, but on CPU, memory and disk hours. different items on the bill. If you got them working just check the quotas page(s) for the app, it *might * already have the info.

Comment: Thanks Dan for your quick and expert help.