# Run headless chrome in GAE Standard Python

Tags: google-app-engine

This article https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-headless-chrome-with-puppeteer says that I now can use headless chrome in GAE Standard (Nodejs). However, current gae project is in Python.

Can I run headless chrome in GAE Standard Python?

Or can my gae app developed in both Python and Nodejs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run headless chrome in the python 2.7 GAE standard due to its [sandbox limitations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime#Python_Pure_Python).

I'm not sure if the newly released 2nd generation standard environment (only supporting python 3.7), which has [fewer restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#restrictions), would allow you to do so - I didn't play with it yet.

But yes, you can mix any combination of languages and GAE environments in your app, as separate services, see [Microservice on GAE+ Mix of Standard and Flexible GAE Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47992254/microservice-on-gae-mix-of-standard-and-flexible-gae-services/47995400#47995400)