# Specifying an AppEngine service with Cloud Endpoints

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I have launched my Endpoints service and deployed my app onto AppEngine.  If I do not specify a service in my app.yaml file, the AppEngine uses the default service.  I am able to make a request using Postman and get a successful response.

However, if I specify my own AppEngine service in my app.yaml file like below, I get a "Not found" error.

```
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1
basic_scaling:
    max_instances: 2
service: mycustomservice
```

What am I missing? How can I get Endpoints/AppEngine to see the mycustomservice service?

Comment: When you do that do you have another service being the default one?

Comment: There is a default service named 'default' in the project. I don't have it manually set in my app.yaml, main.py, or openapi.json files.

Comment: After starting mycustomservice, I stopped the default service.  However, both services had allocation 100%.

Comment: that's fine - I was thinking that a missing default service could be a problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/42360790/4495081

Comment: Did you update the endpoints config files to match the new service name/url? https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/required_files

Comment: I started mycustomservice by including the "service" parameter in app.yaml.  The request url is the same. Is there something else I need to update?

Comment: Hm, the url may not be the same - without a routing change I'd expect the requests going to the same URL to be routed to the default service, not to the new service...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Cloud Endpoints config "openapi-appengine.yaml" set "host" to the path of the non default appengine service you created

default:
`[PROJECT_ID].appspot.com`

additional service
`[SERVICE]-dot-[PROJECT_ID].appspot.com`