# AppEnginge dispatch.yaml url

Tags: google-app-engine

I have this:

```
 - url: "awesome.com/*"
         service: awesome

  - url: "www.awesome.com/*"
          service: awesome
```

Is possible to do this? to achieve same as above?

```
 - url: "*.awesome.com/*"
         service: awesome
```

Answer (score 0):

No, what that last option you mentioned would do is map all subdomains of `awesome.com` to the service `awesome`, as you can see in this [example corresponding to mapping subdomains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#wildcard_mappings) in the documentation.

Here you have more information about [mapping custom domains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to do that. But it won't be equivalent with what you have now:

- it won't match your top-level domain `awesome.com` which is matched by your current 1st rule
- it'll match **any** `<blah>.awesome.com` subdomain, your current set of rules only matches the `www.awesome.com` subdomain

If indeed you want to send requests for both the full domain as well as all its subdomains to the `awesome` service you can achieve that simply by the custom domain mapping/config itself (which you need to do explicitly for the domain and each subdomain anyways), no need for a `dispatch` file. 
Note that you'd still need to deploy a `default` service, see [Why do I need to deploy a "default" app before I can deploy multiple services in GAE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360790/why-do-i-need-to-deploy-a-default-app-before-i-can-deploy-multiple-services-in/42361987#42361987). Might as well just let the `awesome` service be the default one in this case, less confusing and less room for trouble IMHO.