# How do I deploy a dispatch file to a GCP Project without getting an Internal Error with no details

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy a dispatch file in one of our projects, then replicate in the rest of the projects, and I am getting an Internal Error, with no information, a google search has turned up nothing, so I am at a loss on what is wrong. The same error occurs on multiple projects and multiple services, I'm sure there is something wrong with what I am doing, but cannot see it for the life of me

We have custom domains pointed to multiple services, repo is mirrored from Github, each branch deploys to a different service in the project.

The domains are all custom and have successfully been added to the Settings in App Engine for the project, and managed SSL has issued SSL Certificates

We have also forced SSL in the deployment YAML file.

Error Received (deploying from the same dir as dispatch.yaml is located)

```
$ gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INTERNAL: Internal error encountered.
```

Project: is####_webapi

Contents of dispatch.yaml

```
dispatch:
  - url: "api.is####.ai/*"
    service: web-api-prod
  - url: "dev.api.is####.ai/*"
    service: web-api-dev
  - url: "stage.api.is####.ai/*"
    service: web-api-stage
  - url: "www.api.is####.ai/*"
    service: web-api-prod
# gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml
```

App Engine Services (All Standard)

[image: image.png]

Sample Dev App.yaml

```
#gcloud app deploy web-api-dev.yaml --project is####-webapi
service: web-api-dev

runtime: nodejs10
env: standard

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto

env_variables:
    removed for privacy

# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, use different settings

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 5
```

Comment: Do you actually have wildcards in the domain portion of the URL? I don't think that will work: `Tip: You can include glob patterns like the * wildcard character in the url element; however, those patterns can be used only before the host name and at the end of the URL path.`

Comment: No, that was just to remove the name for privacy .. probably a bad choice of craracter on my part. Fixed, thanks ..

Comment: You'd need to specify the project name as well. And did you deploy a default service for the project yet? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42361987/4495081 (shots in the dark)

Comment: Side note: personally I wouldn't recommend implementing environments at the service level, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/43218971/4495081 and linked posts

Comment: Thanks, @DanCornilescu I just solved it, you were very close. yes, aware of the environments at the service level issue, its only temporary right now ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solved.

`gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml --project=projectname` did solve it, but the `Internal Error` was caused by having a Default Project in the SDk Cli that had been deleted on the Cloud Console.