# What's the proper YAML to start a service in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Using Google App Engine, I have an application `myapp` as a default service that adds a task to a task queue and launch a background service worker called `optimize`. Although `myapp` is running fine, unfortunately I always see a POST 404 error in the `myapp` log when the AppEngine task queue tries to launch the URL `/optimize-dot-myapp.appspot.com/index.php/optimize`. Of course because of the 404 error the task queue keeps retrying. My current `optimize.yaml` file contains the following. Any thoughts?

```
# optimize.yaml configuration for Google App Engine
# Full details at: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appref
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
service: optimize

handlers:
# Serve php scripts.
- url: /index.php/optimize
  script: index.php/optimize
```

The default `app.yaml` file contains the following:

```
# app.yaml configuration for Google App Engine
# Full details at: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appref
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php).*
  script: \1
- url: /
  script: index.php

# All URLs beginning with /assets are treated as paths to
# static files in the assets/ directory.
- url: /assets
  static_dir: assets
```

In case it's useful, the `optimize` worker is started in the default task queue with the following PHP:

```
// Start the background worker
// API details: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/refdocs/classes/google.appengine.api.taskqueue.PushTask
$url = '/optimize-dot-myapp.appspot.com/index.php/optimize';
$task = new PushTask($url, $param);
$task_name = $task->add();
```

Comment: how does your default service `.yaml` file look like?

Comment: @DanCornilescu I edited the comments to show the default `app.yaml`. The calling application seems to work fine. It looks like things get stuck when the default task queue tries to launch the `optimize` worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have collisions in the URL path patterns. The `/index.php/optimize` path matches both the `/index.php/optimize` url pattern from `optimize.yaml` **and** the `/(.+\.php).*` pattern from `app.yaml`. Probably the request ends up in the `default` service instead of the `optimize` one. Easy to confirm: check the app logs, you can select a specific service and you'll see which service got the request.

I would add a [`dispatch.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/dispatchref) file to clarify things and eliminate the possibility of ambiguous routing (no need to specify the default module, anything not matching dispatch rules is sent to the default module):

```
application: my_app
dispatch:
  - url: "*/optimize/*"
    module: optimize
```

Then adjust the url patterns accordingly in `optimize.yaml` (they should all start with `/optimize`):

```
- url: /optimize/index.php
  script: index.php
```

Note: the `index.php` file mentioned above would be in the `optimize` service dir, not in the `default` service one. Assuming here that each service has its own dir, as mentioned in [Can a default service/module in a Google App Engine app be a sibling of a non-default one in terms of folder structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110178/can-a-default-module-in-a-google-app-engine-app-be-a-sibling-of-a-non-default-mo)

And in the task enqueueing code the url should only contain the request path, not the hostname (which is interpreted as part of the path, thus causing a mismatch with the handler's url pattern). You want:

```
$url = '/optimize/index.php';
```

Comment: these are all good suggestions. Thanks! For reasons I don't fully understand, only using `dispatch.yaml` didn't route requests to the `optimize` service, however as soon as I dropped the hostname from the task enqueuing code, it started getting the requests.

Comment: I'll update the answer, my comment about it was actually wrong (I'm using python, I thought it's a PHP-specific thing)

Answer (score 0):

In Google App Engine, applications define task queues in a configuration file called queue.yaml. You can use queue.yaml to configure both [push queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/queueref) and [pull queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/overview-pull).

The following a basic example that defines a named queue and overrides the default processing rate:

```
queue:
- name: my-push-queue
  rate: 1/s
```

The following is a more complex example of a queue.yaml configuration that demonstrates setting up task retries and modifying the default processing rate.

```
queue:
- name: fooqueue
  rate: 1/s
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 7
    task_age_limit: 2d
- name: barqueue
  rate: 1/s
  retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 10
    max_backoff_seconds: 200
    max_doublings: 0
- name: bazqueue
  rate: 1/s
  retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 10
    max_backoff_seconds: 200
    max_doublings: 3
```

Please read [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/queueref) documentation for further details

Comment: I am using the default push queue. @bravin I think there's a different problem because according to the [queue.yaml documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/queueref) "This configuration file is optional for push queues, which have a default queue."