# How to structure and run GAE project with both standard and flexible services

Tags: python, google-app-engine

[Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/flexible-for-standard-users) says:

> ... if you have an existing web application running in the
>   standard environment and you want to add a new feature to convert
>   files to PDFs, you can write a separate microservice that runs in the
>   flexible environment that just handles the conversion to PDF.

How would one structure such a project, to be able to deploy these services and also to be able to run them locally?

I was thinking like this:

```
- project/
  - appengine_config.py
  - lib/
  - services/
    - std_service_1/
      - std_service_1.yaml
      - src/
    - std_service_2/
      - std_service_2.yaml
      - src/
    - flex_service/
      - flex_service.yaml
      - src/
```

Then to run locally:

- `dev_appserver.py services/std_service_1/std_service_1.yaml services/std_service_2/std_service_2.yaml`
- `python services/flex_service/src/main.py`

But `lib/` directory cannot be found by `dev_appserver.py` and dependencies fail. I have `vendor.add('lib')` in `appengine_config.py`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could always symlink `lib` into the service directories.

Comment: @Amber I copied the whole `lib` directory to service directories and the problem was still there.

Comment: related, with examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110178/can-a-default-module-in-a-google-app-engine-app-be-a-sibling-of-a-non-default-mo/34111170#34111170