# GAE: How do I run dev_appserver.py?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am having problems configuring a new Windows computer with Google App Engine. The last time I used it with the old computer was more than one year ago and I don't remember if I used the same tools.

Here are the steps I followed:

- Open a cmd window
- `conda create --name gae-firebase python=2`
- `setx CLOUDSDK_PYTHON C:\Anaconda3\envs\gae-firebase\python.exe`
- Close the cmd window
- Download and run [GoogleCloudSDKInstaller.exe](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-windows#before-you-begin) (disabling bundled Python). At the end press 1 to reinitialize the existing configuration, press 1 to keep the existing account, press 2 to select an existing project, press N not to configure the compute engine.
- Open the Google Cloud SDK Shell
- `activate gae-firebase`
- `cd \workspace\google`
- [`git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples.git`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine#cloning_the_sample_app)
- `cd python-docs-samples\appengine\standard\firebase\firenotes`
- [`pip install -r backend\requirements.txt -t lib`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine#installing_dependencies)
- `dev_appserver.py frontend/app.yaml backend/app.yaml` and Answer yes to install the app-engine-python component.

At the end it says `dev_appserver.py: error: too few arguments`

It looks like the script doesn't see the yaml file names in the argument list. I tried to uninstall and reinstall many times changing the order of items or changing other things inspired by the answers to similar questions for hours, but this was the closest I got to success.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In the latest installation of app engine SKD, there is a README file says:

```
RUNNING THE SDK
=========================
You can run the SDK with the following command:

dev_appserver.py [options] <application root>

Application root must be the path to the application to run in this server.
Must contain a valid app.yaml or app.yml file.
```

From what I can see, you didn't provide the `<application root>`. For example, I can run the demo application by:

```
python dev_appserver.py demos\python\guestbook
```

Comment: This only works for apps with just the default service. For multi-service apps the `.yaml` files for the services and the `dispatch.yaml` file, if the app has one, must be passed as arguments. That's because `dev_appserver.py` has no clue how they're named or where they are (they don't have to be in the same dir, see the example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110178/can-a-default-service-module-in-a-google-app-engine-app-be-a-sibling-of-a-non-de/34111170#34111170)

Answer (score 0):

Select any **.py file** press alt + enter(**right mouse click -> properties**) select change then choose python.exe(application) for opening .py file from install directory and run your file... ;-p

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wvrx.png)