# How to view / download the current queue.yaml from GCP?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am attempting to setup a local development version of an existing AppEngine application, I have everything running via dev_appserver and I can access the application, however none of the Task Queues are listed in the local admin interface only 'default' shows. I had hoped to download the queue.yaml and start it with dev_appserver as I did with the services but I cannot find the file anywhere in GCP to download.

I've searched the file system for queue: to no avail, I've searched through the gcloud cli docs and commands, doesn't seem to be any options to download or view only deploy the queue.yaml. There are no options in the GCP UI that I can see.

The queue is called with:

```
(new PushTask('/someUrl', [{params omitted}], ['name' => $taskName]))->add($abc);
```

The application throws the following error because it can't find the queues:

> WARNING: exception 'google\appengine\api\taskqueue\TaskQueueException'
>   with message 'Unknown queue'

How do I view or Download the Queue.yaml from AppEngine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no place in GAE where you can specifically download the deployed `queue.yaml`, which is an app-level config file, shared by all services.

You can see *some*, but not all of the *equivalent* queue configurations parameters in 
 [Cloud Tasks](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudtasks) in the Console developer (where the older [Task queues](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/taskqueues) now redirects). What's notably missing: the retry parameters and the target service (if any). Still, some info you could start with when re-building the `queue.yaml` file.

If you're lucky and symlinked the file into one of your standard environment services to keep the development server happy (see [Google App Engine queue.yaml not working in development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395483/google-app-engine-queue-yaml-not-working-in-development-server/46396894#46396894)) you may find the entire file content copied into the respective service deployment using the method described in: [Google Cloud DataStore automatic indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498821/google-cloud-datastore-automatic-indexing/47499884#47499884)

The typical cause of vanished queues is missing the point that the queue config is shared by all services and deploying a new version of it with just one service in mind. The file content should actually be a combination of *all* queue configs needed by all services.

Comment: Many thanks for your advice, I opted to manually create the queue.yaml using the queue names listed in Task Queues. The dev_appserver complains about rate limits but it does work. For anyone else with this issue: create a blank file called queue.yaml with the following:

`
    queue:
     - {queue_name_a}
     - {queue_name_b}
    ...etc
`
place this file in the root of your local application and (re)start the dev_appserver.