# Can I mix programming languages in a single appengine project?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-appengine-node

I have an existing Java Appengine standard project. I'm writing some new functionality using the beta NodeJS standard environment. The two need to share a common Cloud Datastore database.

Can a single project host both a Java and Node service? If not, how can I share the database between projects?

Comment: You can check all available languages you can use for App Engine flexible and standard environments [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#choosing_your_app_engine_environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have any mix of standard and flexible environment services, written in any languages, see also:

- [Deploying different languages services to the same Application [Google App Engine]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41681288/deploying-different-languages-services-to-the-same-application-google-app-engin/41681718#41681718)
- [Microservice on GAE+ Mix of Standard and Flexible GAE Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47992254/microservice-on-gae-mix-of-standard-and-flexible-gae-services/47995400#47995400)

You don't have to do anything special to share the datastore, it's automatically shared by all app's services.

But you may need to pay extra care to keep the datastore index definitions coherent across all services (the datastore index configuration is an app-level configuration, not a service-level one). See also: [Do I need to define datastore-indexes in every microservice(module) which uses it or just in root application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49156016/do-i-need-to-define-datastore-indexes-in-every-microservicemodule-which-uses-i/49161206#49161206)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a single GCP project can host many App Engine "services", each of these services can be written in a different programming language and use a different environment (Standard or Flexible).

Within one GCP project, you can have:

- Many services per GCP project
- Many versions per service

By default, deployments go to the `default` service, to deploy to a different service, use `service: my-service` in your `app.yaml` file. Read more about how you can structure apps and organize your files on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/configuration-files#examples).

Basically, any deployed App Engine "version" is independent from the other deployed "versions". For example, within one service, you could have the first version running Java, and the next version running Node.js.